# Как мне загружать файлы на Google Drive без авторизации?

Tags: google-drive

Знатоки Google API, помогите. Как мне загружать файлы на Google Drive **без авторизации**? Обычно создают OAuth страницу и там ты даешь доступ к своему аккаунту. Так вот, как этот шаг пропустить? Может гугл дает какие-то ключи, благодаря которым авторизация не нужна?
Что я хочу? Допустим, у меня блог и я не хочу хранить статьи в базе данных или диске, а на Google Drive.
В базе данных хранятся только ID файла на GD и с помощью специальной ссылки я его оттуда вытягиваю и парсю содержимое. Когда автор добавляет статью, она должна записываться в файл и отправляться на GD.
Если бы там был только я автор, то проблем бы не было, но если другие захотят залить на мой GD, тогда у них выйдет окно авторизации.
Этого бы и хотелось избежать.
Возможно, я не совсем понимаю принцип работы Google Drive API, поэтому, если я не прав, укажите на ошибку. Спасибо.

Comment: Для того чтобы кто-то залил на ваш GD файл, вы должны выслать ему ссылку на папку и дать права на запись по учетной записи (обычно это почта). Для чтения это не обязательно если ссылка на файл в GD сделана публичной в настройках этого файла. Не думаю что возможно дать доступ на запись не авторизированному пользователю (хотя, может, как-то и можно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Без ключей" у вас никак не получится. И в данном случае есть три варианта, и все они имеют общую природу. Суть заключается в том, чтобы организовать промежуточный сервис авторизации для работы именно с вашим Диском. Т.о. вы делегируете этому сервису работу с вашими областями доступа.

### Вариант 1

Сервисный аккаунт. Вы можете создать проект и в нем создать сервисный аккаунт, который будет иметь права на доступ к вашему Диску

### Вариант 2

Сервис доступа. Вы должны реализовать сервис доступа, который запрашивает у вас авторизацию и сохраняет токен для последующего самостоятельного взаимодействия с вашим Диском.

### Вариант 3

Работает как сервис доступа. Может работать и с сервисным аккаунтом. Суть его заключается в том, что вы публикуете веб-приложение от своего имени для всех на Google Apps Script. Т.о. вы реализуете второй вариант, но управление авторизацией перекладываете на внешний сервис.

Интересно, что третий вариант можно настроить таким образом, чтобы действительно работать "без ключей", что в общем-то небезопасно.